# Android: Firebase Realtime database abnormal data consumption (correct configuration of the rules)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When launching the following queries by my android app firebase realtime database experiencing abnormal data consumption:

The follow is the first QUERY

```
  final DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Linea/Materiale/"+ordine+prodottoPath);
        rootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
.....
 qunatitareppNew = f.parse(snapshot.child("quantitarepp").getValue().toString()).floatValue();
...
```

The follow is the second QUERY

```
 FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();


        DatabaseReference myRef2 = database.getReference("Tasks");

        Query query2 = myRef2
                .orderByChild("idmacrofase")
                .equalTo(idMacro);

        query2.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot2) {
                for (DataSnapshot snap : dataSnapshot2.getChildren()) {

                     final String idtask = snap.child("idtask").getValue().toString();

.....
```

I config the follow rule file in firebase realtime database rules:

```
{
  
  "rules":{
    ".read": "auth !== null",
    ".write": "auth !== null",
   
     
    "Tasks": {
    ".indexOn": ["idmacrofase","idpick","idrotolo","idtask","lastupdate",".value","dataconsegna","prodotto","checkCS"]
    },
    "Linea":{
          ".indexOn":["Materiale",".value"],
            "Materiale":{ ".indexOn":[".value","quantitarepp","quantita","ordine"]},
        }
    
  }
  
}
```

Here i wrote and example of my realtime databese :

```
.......

 "Linea" : {
    "Materiale" : {
      "300232044211vj01592b226" : {
        "ordine" : "300232044",
        "quantita" : "4"
      },
      "300232044211vu01315b205" : {
        "ordine" : "300232044",
        "quantita" : "4"
      },

.....

 "Tasks" : {
    "101698446" : {
      "idmacrofase" : "1620057379ABSI402",
      "idpick" : "0030308174",
      "idrotolo" : "1620057379ABSI",
      "idtask" : 101698446,
      "lastupdate" : "1620057379758",
    },
```

how can i change the rules to reduce data consumption?

Comment: What do you mean by "abnormal data consumption"?

Comment: I would expect to have download traffic of a few Mb and instead generate download traffic of Gb